# M_PI_2 missing from clang on Windows

Tags: c, clang, math.h

I make use of M_PI_2 from [math.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/math.h.html) in my source code.

This works fine for my Linux, OSX, iOS and Android builds.

When I use the clang compiler for Windows, I get:

`use of undeclared identifier 'M_PI_2'`

Why is there no M_PI_2 for my clang compiler on Windows? I compile with `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L`

```
$ clang --version
clang version 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

Comment: did you check the content of math.h?

Comment: That's not in the C standard, and the Windows C standard library implementation thus probably doesn't bother to define it.

Comment: `M_PI_2` is not part of standard C.  Consider writing code to the C standard and use `#define MY_PI_2 (3.1415926535897932384626433832795/2)` or `#define MY_PI_2 (asin(-1)/2)` or the like.

Comment: Since when is Windows POSIX/UNIX compatible? Read the headline of the linked page.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite And yet, with _USE_MATH_DEFINES it behaves as required, thereby solving my problem. Valid problem. Valid solution. What's your problem?

Answer (score -1):

So, from `ucrt/corecrt_math_defines.h` I see that:

*"Define **_USE_MATH_DEFINES** before including  to expose these macro definitions..."*